# Does a county court circuit judge’s decision in Birmingham bind a district judge in London?

Tags: england-and-wales, jurisdiction, appeal, precedent

They are more senior but in a different region of the English “county court.”

So how does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if it's a binding precedent.

And it could be the other way round, also. The main difference is that district judges hear the higher value, more complex and/or protracted cases.

Comment: But anyway, what makes it a binding precedent? What determines what type of ruling is each one?

Comment: And did you mean to say that circuit judges hear the higher value etc cases? Honestly, I’m sorry to say it but I have to say that you have hardly really answered the question at all.

Comment: Are you arguing that trial court judgments are binding precedents?

Comment: @ohwilleke me, or Rick?

Comment: @Seekinganswers Rick.

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe

Your [circuit judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_judge_(England_and_Wales)) could be a member of the Crown Court, the County Court or a specialized sub-division of the High Court of Justice.

The hierarchy of the courts of England and Wales is:

[Court hierarchy England and Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courts_of_England_and_Wales#/media/File:Diagram_of_the_court_system_of_England_and_Wales_2014.svg)

The Crown Court and the County Court are the same level so they do not create binding precedent on themselves or each other. If your circuit judge is a member of the High Court then their decisions do bind the County Court.

England and Wales is a unified jurisdiction so it doesn’t matter where the courts are located. There is no such thing as a “circuit split” as can happen in the US Federal system.

Comment: Sorry my circuit judges were intended to be ruling on civil case in the county court. Thanks

Comment: Please see  the edit and clarification to my question.

Comment: The question above is answered above

Comment: Sorry but I don’t really think it is. The question is whether a county court CJ, whether in London or elsewhere’s, rulings bind a county court’s DJ, whether elsewhere in London or elsewhere entirely. And that doesn’t seem to me answered in the above.

Comment: @Seekinganswers A CJ and a DJ both make decisions for the County Court. Neither outranks the other.

Comment: How can that be when one appeals from a DJ to a CJ?

Comment: Because one doesn’t. One appeals to the https://www.gov.uk/courts-tribunals/court-of-appeal-civil-division

Comment: I thought one appeals from a CCDJ to a CCCJ and then from a CCCJ to the EWHC, and only then to the EWCA.